# Stapling wire during remodel?

Tags: electrical

Probably a fairly silly question, but for peace of mind, when running/fishing wire behind drywall during a kitchen remodel, I obviously cannot staple the wire to studs unless I remove the drywall and/or cut out holes so I can reach in with pliers/hammer to get a staple in. Is it ok if the romex is floating/loose back there, and not stapled? This is for hardwired under cabinet lighting.

Answer (score 5):

### This is fine

Not stapling fished NM cables in remodel work is permitted by NEC 334.30(B) point 1:

> **(B) Unsupported Cables.** Nonmetallic-sheathed cable shall be
> permitted to be unsupported where the cable:
>
> (1) Is fished between access points through concealed spaces
> in finished buildings or structures and supporting is
> impracticable.

So, fish away, and don't worry about tearing up drywall to get staples in.

Comment: Great answer, I've wondered about this myself....learned another thing from SE today!  Thanks.